# Why alert AnchorElement (<a>) alerts the href attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

```
<a href="url">A link</a>

$.each($('a'), function(index,value){
    alert (value)
});
```

It will alert : `url`.
Why this happens?

Comment: Why are you not using `console.log`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the `toString()` of the anchor gives the URL.

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FC3n4/)

`alert` calls `toString()` implicity on objects.  so when you alert an array like:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Alerting it will give you:

```
"1,2,3,4,5,6"
```

Because the toString() of `array` is the elements separated by a comma.

If you encounter this problem while debugging, you should use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`

Comment: It returns URL even without toString()

Comment: @Daniil. Nope, `alert` call `toString()` implicity.

Answer (score 3):

`value` is `HTMLAnchorElement` object, `HTMLAnchorElement.toString()` method return its url attribute.

`alert` will use `.toString()` when display an object.

Answer (score 0):

the reason you get url is because .each takes a container(array||object) and then uses your callback function to process the container. it will take an array's elements, or an object's properties, and iterate over them.  since the property of your selector object is "href", you will get the url value.

Comment: This is not true, you can see the DEMO in my answer.