# How do I get .each to pass an HTMLAnchorElement in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why alert AnchorElement (<a>) alerts the href attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076627/why-alert-anchorelement-a-alerts-the-href-attribute)

Is it possible to get JQuery to pass HTMLAnchorElement objects when using `.each` instead of the href value?  I created a demonstration at http://jsbin.com/welcome/70301/edit.  I would expect it to pop up `[object HTMLDivElement]` followed by `[object HTMLAnchorElement]`, but instead the second popup displays the href (`http://twitter.com/js_bin`) for the anchor element. Why? How can I get the desired behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine if you log to console instead of alert. ALert is not a good tool for elements, or for that matter, debugging in general. If you are unfamiliar with browser console do a search. WIll save you many many hours of guessing what's going on in your code

Comment: Note that further experimentation on my part also demonstrated that `console.log` can be similarly misleading in some browsers.  For instance, when testing the above jsbin demonstration and substituting `console.log` for `alert`, I got useful output on Chrome and Firefox, but undefined on IE 9.  When testing similar code in the actual browser, Firefox and IE 9 reported the href in the console log, while Chrome did report the HTMLAnchorElement (albeit displayed somewhat differently).